# WebBrowser control emulation not working when passing POST parameters

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, axwebbrowser

In my application I use the WebBrowser control.

Since the content requires a higher version of IE - I used the *FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION* as explained here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx

this worked perfectly until I needed to include some parameters as *POST*, so I used the following overload of the 'Navigate' method:

```
Navigate(string urlString, string targetFrameName, byte[] postData, string additionalHeaders)
```

But since I started using this new overload, the WebBrowser's emulation stopped working.

I used SysInternals' Process-Monitor and it is clearly visible that when using *POST* parameters - the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION key is not accessed.